# Не выводит значение переменной Pascal

Tags: pascal

Проблема в том, что код работает но не выводит значение  j после нажатия на Esc

```
program untitled;
uses crt;

var i, o, j : integer;
    k:char;
BEGIN
    i := 0;
    o := 0;
    j := 0;
    k := chr(32);

   //по нажатию на esc должен произойти вывод на экран номера запятой и завершение программы
    while k<>chr(27) do begin 
        k := readkey;
        write(k);
        inc(i);
        if k = chr(44) then begin // если символ запятая то
            inc(o);               // прибавить к счетчику запятых 1

            if o = 1 then begin   // если в счетчике запятых значение 1(первая запятая) 
                write(i);         // то вывести ее номер
            end; 
            j := i;               // каждый раз присваивать j номер введенной запятой   
            write(j);             // эта строка просто в качестве проверки
                                  // правильно ли присваивается значение введенной запятой(СПОЙЛЕР: правильно) 
        end
    end;

    if j<>0 then                  // весь дальнейший код должен выполняться поcле нажатия на Esc
         write(j)
    else write('none');           // а вот эта строчка отрабатывает как нужно 
                                  // (введите любой символ кроме запятой и нажмите Esc)
 END.
```

Просьба не советовать массивы символов и строки для решения задачи. Это учебная задача на символы и никакие другие типы не принимаются.

> Задача: Дана последовательность из n символов. Известно, что в последовательности имеется хотя-бы одна запятая. 
>   Найти номер:
>   а) первой по порядку запятой;
>   б) последней по порядку запятой.

Т.е в данном примере номер первой запятой выводится, но последнее значение счетчика запятых(по нажатию Esc) - нет.

Не смотрю готовые решения т.к задачу решил, осталась только эта деталь и я хочу понять, в чем ошибка

Comment: вы выводите `j` - номер последнего символа, а не последней запятой. Вам нужно куда-то сохранять индекс запятой, когда вы ее встречаете, а в конце вывести.

Comment: да, уже обновил коммент

Comment: @teran а разве `j:=i` не подходит?

Comment: упс, действительно.

Comment: вы уверены что не получается так, что прогарамма закрылась и вы не успели увидеть, что она там вывела?

Comment: @teran [Видео на Youtube](https://youtu.be/nrVdK6seTSk)

Comment: а `none` точно выводит? а то ощущение что `esc` перехватывается, и просто завершается работа. либо я туплю сегодня люто.

Comment: @teran да, это точно [Вот](https://youtu.be/H7hNJLPbdSs)

Comment: отладчик то у вас есть там? поставьте брейк на if, и смотрите, что он делает.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вам переменная 'o'?.. Ведь первая запятая определяется по условию `if j = 0 then ...`.

Comment: И в Delphi 7 этот код нормально работает, так что проблема, похоже, в вашем компиляторе (интерпретаторе?) паскаля.